# Single Sign on integration with cloud based asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap

We have a SAAS web application which houses it's own user authenications (user names => Passwords). A client is asking to have this integrated with their internal Active Directory. For this client this is mainly to have their password management in the one place active directory side of things but also if we can achieve it single sign on abilities.

Has anyone achieved integrating AD/SSO with an external cloud based Asp.net web application? I have seen third party providers like OKTA and one Login that seem like they could help achieve this but wondering if anyone has gone down this path?

Comment: Write a web service on client side which integrates with their AD and expose login methods which you can consume in your SAAS application. We have one application hosted outside our network and it uses web service to allow employees to login using their windows credential. Only thing is we have to expose web service hosted in our internal network to be available to outside world.

Comment: Hi Hakunamatata (love the name as well), thanks for the reply. I do like the idea, you didnt have any security concerns exposing the AD authentication externally? Also you didnt try to achieve SSO in anyway with this setup?

Comment: We have secured web service itself and operations team put IP restriction so only external website can connect to it. We are only exposing login method which takes users's credentials and check if that user is valid user and belong to specific AD group and returns true/false response. We have only one external app so we did not need to worry about SSO.  ADFS is another option for SSO but that is bit involved for our purpose.